# How to make Docusaurus work with ESM only package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, docusaurus

I am authoring a TS library that compiles to ESM-only package and has `"type": "module"` set in its `package.json` file. For the same package, I am trying to generate documentation using docusaurus. The project structure is:

```
|- ROOT
|  |-- src (TS source code library)
|  |-- site (The docusaurus.config.ts file and docs `src/` folder)
|  |-- tsconfig.json (For docusaurus project)
|  |-- tsconfig.lib.json (For building the library only)
|  |-- package.json (Contains package definition along with docusaurus dependencies).
```

I do not want to move to monorepo just for the sake of maintaining the documentation with Docusaurus. The Docusaurus works, compiles fine with TS and ESM configuration but it breaks at runtime when I try to load the website.

Is there any way I can solve this problem? It is hard to identify which files Webpack is trying to read as CJS as docusaurus generates many temporary files.